# Django Ajax Get method giving 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Tags: django, ajax

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btn_create_card", function () {
  url1 = $(this).attr("data-url");

  $.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      description: "test",
    },
    success: function () {
      console.log("sucess");
      Get_CardView();
    },
  });
});
```

Below is my Class-based view for the call

```
  class CreateCard(View):

      def get(self, request):
          description1 = request.GET.get('description', None)
          print(description1)

          return redirect('/')
```

but I am getting below error message

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_card?description=test 405 (Method Not Allowed)

below is my url

```
path('create_card',  views.CreateCard.as_view(), name='create_card'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried for nearly an hour and realized it is due to change of URL name. I renamed 'Book' to 'Card' for all functions and URL.

seems like Django is retrieving from .pyc.

Deleting .pyc files and re-run it resolved.